# Aeron cluster intercommunication

Tags: aeron

i want to understand aeron cluster inter communication

Hi,
I am new in Aeron Cluster and I try to understand the relations between the various cluster's components.

From https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Cluster-Tutorial :

4.3. Running the Cluster
Now we have a configured cluster, we can start it running. The code for launching the service is as follows.

try (
ClusteredMediaDriver clusteredMediaDriver = ClusteredMediaDriver.launch(
mediaDriverContext, archiveContext, consensusModuleContext);                             // (1)
ClusteredServiceContainer container = ClusteredServiceContainer.launch(
clusteredServiceContext))                                                                // (2)
{
System.out.println("[" + nodeId + "] Started Cluster Node on " + hostname + "...");
barrier.await();                                                                             // (3)
System.out.println("[" + nodeId + "] Exiting");
}

I do not understand how the ClusteredServiceContainer communicate with the ClusteredMediaDriver .
I mean that in the code above each object constructed independently .What is the "glue" between them ?

Answer (score 0):

`MediaDriver.Context` `ClusteredServiceContainer.Context` they use the same `aeronDirectoryName` in the above, share the same file on the disk or memory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).